# Use SELECT database laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

i have a problem with my database please help me

```
select *from `parts` 
    where `code` in ('2976', '1620', '1619', '2977') 
    and `date` != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
    group by `code` 
    order by `created_at` desc
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is, mate.

Comment: what should I do

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to utilize Laravel's `Query Builder` to do this, it's as simple as this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('parts')
    ->whereIn('code', [2976, 1620, 1619, 2977])
    ->where('date', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    ->groupBy('code')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Really though you should [have a look over the documentation, it's all explained here clearly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

Comment: i add this any file i put it